# showing the bottom of the div content with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, crop

basically i got a div with a lot of content, like:

```
<div>
top of content </br>
some content </br>
some  content </br>
some  content </br>
some  content </br>
some  content </br>
some  content </br>
some  content </br>
bottom of content 
</div>
```

then, im setting a height for the div, and overflow, so it will "crop" the div. like this:

```
<style>
div{
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

what i'd like to do, is that the div will show the end of the content, not the top of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give an id to your div (e.g. "myDiv") and then by javascript try:

> document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollTop =
>   document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollHeight;

Comment: +1 for simplicity and same solution. Just created an fiddle for that: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q696S/)

Comment: its working, but when i use it in Jquery, somehow it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but feels kinda hacky.  This works, for example:

```
<style>
.first {
max-height: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.second {
float:right;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}


</style>

<div class="first">
<div class="second">
blah blah<br/>
blah blah<br/>
</div>
</div>
```

You're just rotating the first div and nesting it inside another div that rotates the content back.  The overflow is hiding the 'bottom' of the rotated containing div and the content is rotated.  (It's a bit weird, but does work.)